# Javascript: how to replace random-value by value from XML-file?

Tags: javascript, xml

At one side I have a JavaScript based on a example from Justgage's website with random generators to provide demonstration values.
The intention is to display values from an XML-file.

Adaptation of min, max, label, title etc. is no problem, resulting in below script *segment* which defines the function for var g1, and is repeated for variables g2, g3 and g4

```
window.onload = function(){
  var g1 = new JustGage({
    id: "g1",
    value: getRandomInt(100, 200),
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    title: "Power",
    label: "W"
    textRenderer: customValue1
  });
```

At other side an XML-file, which contains the values for gauge_power, gauge_temp, gauge_vpv and gauge_iac to be imported to the Javascript to 'fill' respectively g1, g2, g3 and g4.

```
<response>
 <gauge_power>1300</gauge_power>
 <gauge_temp>0.0</gauge_temp>
 <gauge_vpv>103.0</gauge_vpv>
 <gauge_iac>0.0</gauge_iac>
 <energy_today>2.658</energy_today>
 <energy_total>7324.9</energy_total>
 <hours_total>17490</hours_total>
 <time_stamp>20161017 13:32</time_stamp>
</response>
```

In my view I need to replace the script-line

```
value: getRandomInt(100, 200),
```

by an alternative 'call' which for g1 extracts the value of gauge_power from the XML-file.

Have tried several example solutions from StackOverflow, but without result.

*Kindly requesting (a hint for) a working solution for this case*

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. What values do you want to extract from your xml and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Extraction of value of <gauge_power> from the XML-file, and using that value as described in the bottom 5 lines of the question.

Comment: Do you want to know how to parse an xml in javascript?

Comment: Nikhil, that is exactly the question. For import of the xml-file have been looking at e.g. the following 4 lines, but apparently 'somewhere I miss the connection' to get a successful import as a start to continue with Caisah's answer for extraction of values.  // var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// request.open("GET", "/path/demo.xml", false);
// request.send();
// var xml = request.responseXML;

Answer (score 0):

```
function createGage(val){
  return new JustGage({
    id: "g1",
    value: val,
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    title: "Power",
    label: "W"
    textRenderer: customValue1
  });


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/file.xml", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    var xml = xhr.responseText;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var domFragment = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
    var gaugePower = domFragment.querySelector('gauge_power').textContent;

    createGage(gaugePower);
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Answer certainly is step forward to get real values inside the javascript.
But my xml-file is 'outside' the javascript. Also a quick hint available to read an 'external' xml-file into a javascript?

Comment: Where do you get the `xml` file from? Is it from your local machine? Do you host it on a server?

Comment: I have included an AJAX request in the response. You have to replace `/path/to/file.xml` with your proper location. This doesn't include error handling tough.

Comment: This specific xml-file (and a bunch of other json-files and xml-files) are periodically being uploaded from various local machines to my (local and remote) webservers, where the json- and xml-files are saved in the same directory as the related html-pages incl. the javascript-lines. This specific piece of Javascript was a problem, because lacking knowledge/routine/examples for the combination of JustGage and data-extraction.

Comment: Caisah, If you compare your AJAX-addition with the example lines which I put in my response to Nikhil, I start to see where I had a 'missing link'.
;-) Enough information to spent the weekend trying to get it into the webpage-under-test, for g1, g2, g3 and g4.